# Should I not reply to my girlfriend's text messages containing "kisses/hugs" or "I love you" when fasting in Ramadan?

Tags: ramadan, sawm

My girlfriend is currently not in the same timezone as I am. So my fasting starts before hers. We usually text during the time I prepare meal etc. and while I eat or after the feast starts she will occasionally say stuff like kisses/hugs or I love you.

Should I not reply to that after my fasting has started, or I can reply because she is not near me.

Can this impact my fasting?

Comment: well, regardless of fasting being invalid or not, having relationship with a girl is itself haram or forbidden. Sawm makes halal things haram for a while, but haram remain haram always. I'd advise you as a muslim brother (taking that you're also a muslim) to stay away from such relationships.

Answer (score 6):

Bismillah

Things that spoil(break) fasting are following:

- Eating
- Drinking
- Intercourse
- Ejaculation in a awake state (whether it happened during touching of a woman body, kissing, masturbating or alike)
- Infusion (Feeding through needle)
- Child-birth bleeding (nifas) or vaginal bleeding (istihada) for females

Anything else besides the aforementioned, does not spoil fasting.

From things that **do not** spoil fasting are following:

- Putting eye-drops in eye,ear or nose
- Vomiting
- Extracting blood (like blood tests or blood donation)
- Doing Al-hijaamah (cupping) // see http://islamqa.info/en/ref/3268/hijama for more info
- Blood coming out of the nose
- Bleeding
- Pulling your teeth out
- Mezij fluid flowing (fluid that comes before sperm, unlike sperm mezij is not as white as sperm, and usually comes out when one is aroused)
- Using tooth-paste
- Taking injection that are not Infusions

Therefore, saying to a girl that you like here or something similar does not spoil fasting. However, you should know that flirting with that girl, which is haram (forbidden) according to Islamic Sharia (law), is a question that you are not asking about, but you still should know detail Islamic view about. So I suggest heading over to http://islamqa.info/ and reading questions about that.

Esselamu alaykum wa rahmetullahi wa berakatuhu.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that even an actual physical kiss doesn't invalidate a fast.

> A'isha (RA) reported that the Messenger of
>   Allah (ﷺ) used to kiss her during the month of fasting. [( Sahih
>   Muslim  Book 13, Hadith 89)](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/13/89)

In another Hadith:

> Narrated Umar ibn al-Khattab:
>
> I got excited, so I kissed while I was fasting, I then said: Messenger
>   of Allah, I have done a big deed; I kissed while I was fasting. He
>   said: What do you think if you rinse your mouth with water while you
>   are fasting. The narrator Isa ibn Hammad said in his version: I said
>   to him: There is no harm in it. Then both of them agreed on the
>   version: He said: Then what? [(Sunan Abi Dawud Book 14, Hadith 73)](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/14/73)

What scholars say is one should be aware of one's will power. If a man is not able to control himself after the kiss and takes things forward it may lead to actions invalidating his/her fast. Hence, incase of such a scenario it is advisable to practice restrain.

W.r.t your query, it is highly unlikely that a text message would cause you to perform actions that may invalidate your fast. The text message itself or if your wife is physically present, then the actual kiss itself will not break your fast.

**Note**:
Islam doesn't allow premarital relationships. Hence the concept of girlfriend/boyfriend and as per some scholars even fiancee/fiance is foreign to Islam.